# Global variable Backbone not showing up in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, backbone.js

I'm following a tutorial for learning Backbone, but Chrome isn't displaying for me what the tutorial says it should be.

I have an index.html file with the script tags referencing underscore.js, jquery and backbone.js files, but the chrome console does not display the Backbone variable. I've tried installing backbone, underscore and jquery with both bower and node, but it didn't change anything.

my index.html file

```
<head>

    <meta charset='utf-8'>

</head>

<body>


    <script src='underscore.js'></script>
    <script src='jquery-2.1.4.js'></script>
    <script src='backbone.js'></script>

</body>
```

According to the tutorial, I should see the global variable Backbone in the chrome Developer Tools console, but it's a blank space...

If I need to provide anything else, let me know. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are the JS files in the same directory as the index page?

Comment: @epascarello Yes, they are.

Comment: Any errors in the Browser's console?

Comment: @epascarello Not anymore. I had one for the JQuery file, but I fixed that. I literally have a blank console.

Comment: @epascarello Okay, I just changed the files to the production version and now I have a caution, "the key 'target-densitydpi' is not supported.

Comment: @epascarello And now it's gone again.

Comment: Have you tried typing 'Backbone' into the developer console? That should get you the Backbone object so you can take a look at whats inside.

Comment: @trolle Wow, I must be an idiot. It showed up. The tutorial I was following made it sound like it should just be visible upon opening the console... Thanks for the response.

Comment: Sounds like a bad tutorial :). Here is a free book with plenty of code examples: http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/

Comment: @trolle Thanks a lot. I'll definitely give that a look. I really appreciate the response.